# make post request by using superagent, it sent out as get

Tags: node.js, post, superagent

I  made a post request by using superagent:

```
var postUsage = function(postUsage_CB) {
    var expectedStatusCode =  201;
    var timeStart = new Date();
    request
        .post(serviceEndPoint)
        .send(object)
        .end(function(err, res) {

            resCode = res.statusCode;
            console.log('\n' + 'postUsage - res.statusCode = ',resCode);

            if (res.statusCode != expectedStatusCode){
              console.log('\n' + 'postUsage - res.text = ',res);
              throw 'POST usage failed';
            }
            else {
              header_location = res.headers.location;
              return postUsage_CB();
            }
        });
  };
```

While I see inside the response in the header, it says the request method is get.
And also I could see in the log info of endpoint I am posting to, it showing the method is get. 
Anyone knows what's going on with it?

Comment: have you ever figured out what caused this? I am seeing the same problem.

Comment: @Redsandro it turns out an other problem cause this issue. Not related to superagent